# Attempted import errors in react-native-web monorepo architecture

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack, babeljs, react-native-web

**Hi there,**

I am following [this article](https://dev.to/brunolemos/tutorial-100-code-sharing-between-ios-android--web-using-react-native-web-andmonorepo-4pej) to setup a react-native + web code sharing. [Here is the repo link](https://github.com/brunolemos/react-native-web-monorepo) with bare-bone monorepo setup as described in above article.

**I successfully did setup bare-bone monorepo app as described in above article, than i ported my existing react-native app code to this architecture(in the components folder) and got mobile app working and everything.**

I am getting some errors when i try to run web app(which used react-native-web to convert react-native to web). Its not that i was not expecting some errors, i know `react-native-web` is yet not that stable and not that up to date for react-native version above 0.55 and all those gotchas.

But the errors i am getting here are more related to my webpack config i think. My `config-override.js` file is basically the same as [original one](https://github.com/brunolemos/react-native-web-monorepo/blob/master/packages/web/config-overrides.js) except this part(which i changed in a hope to get through the errors i will mention below):

```
const appIncludes = [
  resolveApp('src'),
  resolveApp('../components/src'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-navigation-deprecated-tab-navigator'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-color-matrix-image-filters'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-htmlview'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-cookies'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-router-flux'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-actionsheet'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-autocomplete-input'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-circular-progress'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-google-places-autocomplete'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-image-progress'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-image-zoom-viewer'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-image-pan-zoom'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-permissions'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-phone-input'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-picker-select'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-progress'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-push-notification'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-svg'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-tab-view'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-navigation-drawer'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-navigation-stack'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-screens'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-navigation-tabs'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/@react-navigation'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-router-flux'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'),
  resolveApp('../../node_modules/react-navigation'),
]
```

Couple or errors i am getting on `yarn workspace web start` are:

```
import {
    Grayscale
} from 'react-native-color-matrix-image-filters';
```

It gives:

> Attempted import error: 'Grayscale' is not exported from
>   'react-native-color-matrix-image-filters'.

If i just remove this import and its use, i than get:

> Attempted import error: 'react-native-cookies' does not contain a
>   default export (imported as 'CookieManager').

On:

```
import CookieManager from 'react-native-cookies';
```

While playing around, i also got:

```
...../node_modules/react-native-router-flux/src/navigationStore.js
Attempted import error: 'TabBarBottom' is not exported from 'react-navigation-deprecated-tab-navigator' (imported as 'DEPRECATED_TabBarBottom').
```

I am pretty sure this is something wrong with my webpack/babel config(`config-override.js` file). And i certainly know i will get more errors after resolving these. And this setup might end up not working at all for us. But it worths a try and i must be able to get through these errors with your help.

Thanks.

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54553728/4738391

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get past this error by adding:
`config.module.strictExportPresence = false` in the `config-override.js`

Now i am stuck on further issues.

Original issue in the question is gone by this. I will post with any other related updates if i have any.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably not use these packages on the web since they're react native packages (Android and iOS) and not web packages.

Which means that you have to split the files that import and use these packages.

Example of creating a wrapper for CookieManager: cookieManagerWrapper.js(everything else: Android and iOS) and cookieManagerWrapper.web.js(Web only).

In the web specific js file, you don't import CookieManager but import an alternative web library instead to implement the same functionality as on mobile but with different code that works on the web.

Then you can import and use cookieManagerWrapper.js everywhere and react-native-web will automatically substitute it with the cookieManagerWrapper.web.js when available.

Some react native packages do work on web too when they're only consisting of platform independent JavaScript code. Also some packages have web implementations that can be aliased in webpack like react-native-gradients with react-native-web-gradients, sadly this is not the case with the packages mentioned in the question.

This file splitting with file.js, file.web.js, file.android.js and file.ios.js makes it possible to write different implementations for each platform. This is also great for some user interface code, you can use 3rd party react components on the web and 3rd party react native components on mobile that look similar to implement more complex user interactions since react native web supports all regular react code and jsx tags on the web.

Comment: Thank-you so much for your answer, when i posted the question i had a much shorter list of packages, now i have around 20 of them after the attempted import error was fixed. I did replaced and upgraded a few libraries on the way until i got compilation, it was later than in the browser i am getting errors like `react-native-cookies: Invalid platform. This library only supports Android and iOS.` so the wrapper pattern you have described makes perfect sense. I will go with that. Also i will update my question with all dependencies, any additional notes about them would be great.